# Apply SVG mask to image

Tags: html, svg

Hi I have been stuck on this problem for a while now.

Basically I am trying to follow [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content) and [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/3213/=maskdemo.xhtml) which explains how to mask an element using the *mask* CSS property and an embedded SVG image with Firefox.

```
<style>.target { mask: url(#m1); }</style>  

<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/08/DioHolyDiver.jpg/220px-DioHolyDiver.jpg" alt="" class="target" />

<svg width="220" height="220">
<mask maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="m1">
<linearGradient y2="0.5" x2="0.6" y1="0.5" x1="0" id="g">
    <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
    <stop stop-opacity="0" stop-color="white" offset="1"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect id="svg_1" height="220" width="220" y="0" x="0" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#g)"/>
</mask>
</svg>
```

You can see my attempt here http://jsfiddle.net/pjgalbraith/cnLHE/. As you can see it just displays a blank image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
   <rect id="svg_1" height="220" width="220" y="0" x="0" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#g)"/>
```

x and y should be greater than 0 and less than 1 and there is no gradient because height and width should be less

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<body>

  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/08/DioHolyDiver.jpg/220px-DioHolyDiver.jpg" alt="" class="target" />


  <style>.target { mask: url(#m1); } </style>

  <svg:svg width="220" height="220">
    <svg:mask maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="m1">
      <svg:linearGradient id="g" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" y2="0.5" x2="0.6" y1="0.5" x1="0">
        <svg:stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
        <svg:stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" offset="1"/>
      </svg:linearGradient>
      <svg:rect id="svg_1" x="0.5" y="0.2" width="0.5" height="0.8" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#g)"/>
    </svg:mask>
  </svg:svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. However it is still showing up blank for me. See http://jsfiddle.net/pjgalbraith/cnLHE/13/

Comment: Can you create a gist on github (http://gist.github.com/). I would love to see the working file. Also if it is public then others can benefit. I can't send a pm on this site and I would rather not post my email here.

Comment: https://www.yousendit.com/dl?phi_action=app/orchestrateDownload&rurl=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.yousendit.com%252Ftransfer.php%253Faction%253Dbatch_download%2526batch_id%253DM3BtL0dKYUlOQnpMYnRVag&s=19102&cid=tx-02002207340200000000

Comment: Thanks gidzior! I have updated the jsfiddle as well with the working version http://jsfiddle.net/pjgalbraith/cnLHE/

Comment: Not works in chrome though... Looks like the only way to make it work in most major browsers is to put raster image in svg like here:
https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/
(see "SVG mask for SVG elements")